# Modify Script When Inserted into Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have code that is pulling a script from an external site.

```
var url = "//example.com/script-url.js";
 $.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'jsonp'
});
```

It works fine, however, the script it pulls is generated by a third party site. The script it pulls in I need to modify when it loads into my site.

The third party script starts with this:

```
(function() {

   document.getElementById("weedmenuPane").innerHTML = //script continues
```

further in the script is another instance of `weedmenuPane`.

I need to modify the ID `weedmenuPane` to another ID. Is there a way to do this when the script is inserted into my site?

Note: I have no control over the third party script being insert into the site.

Comment: To make sure I understood it correctly - script A (from your domain) gets and executes script B (not from your domain) by JSONP, and you are wondering if you can change something in script B between loading and executing? Most likely no, since JSONP avoids Same Origin Policy. If you were given access by the admins of script B, then you could load their script by plain AJAX (not JSONP), modify and inject into your code; but that requires the owners of B to know you and allow you access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this script is coming from a third party site, it is a cross origin script.  As such, you cannot use an Ajax call to retrieve it directly unless the server it is on happens to support CORS.

From the client, it can only be used as JSONP by inserting it as a `<script>` tag which will execute it immediately before you get an opportunity to modify it.  So, no luck here.

The other choice is to have your client request the script from your server.  Your server can then retrieve it from the other site (no cross origin limitations when accessed by your server).  Your server can then modify the script before returning it to your client.

---

FYI, another work-around seems like perhaps you could temporarily modify your site to use the `weedmenuPane` id while the script runs (so that it operates on your desired object) and then after the script runs, you can restore the id to whatever you had before.

Comment: You answered my question. Thank You!